# Hbase Coprocessor Aggregation on fetched rows

Tags: hbase, aggregation

We have an use case wherein we will need to land large volumes of sales data into Hadoop.  Then the user base would consume this data. Users would be doing further aggregations & might do sum, avg, count etc.

The need to have the query return results fast. So, we are exploring hbase instead of just hive. Below is sample data.

Date    Store   Invoice Item    sales   expenses
1-Jan   1   100 312312  43  24
2-Jan   3   101 344324  434 232
3-Jan   2   102 342344  34  23

I am aware that using Hbase coprocessor endpoints, aggregations could be done avoiding mapreduce job & with low latency. But not sure how to implement it when the user fetches only a subset of  rows.
Suppose, user wants to see sum of sales for items 1 & 2 in the above case, then the result should be 77 & query should return the result in few secs max.
Another user might want to see the sales for items 2 & 3. Appreciate your advice.